# Score count in quiz

Tags: c#

Hi all I am making a windows store app using VS 2012. One of the elements will be a quiz which I am trying to make a score counter for that will display the user's current score.

So currently I have created an integer and an increment for when the correct answer is selected. I have made a textbox to display the score but not sure how to display the score in it? Which event handler would be suitable to use in this situation? I already wrote the code that should convert the integer to a string so it can displayed in the textbox.

```
private void RadioButtonQTEN3_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    feedback10.Text = "Correct";
    RadioButtonQTEN2.IsEnabled = false;
    RadioButtonQTEN3.IsEnabled = false;
    score++;
}

int score = 0;



private void dispScore_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    dispScore.Text = score.ToString();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code and narrow down your question.

Comment: Why don't you just display it when you increment it rather than looking for a new event handler?

Comment: If you set the `Text` in the `TextChanged` event aren't you going to recursion yourself to death?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) interface. You can listen to the [propertychanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged) event and update the textbox everytime the score changes. Of course, you will need an object to store the current score.